# How to color SVG image based on value from color range using d3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create a range of SVG images that represent a member in a team. The number of `person` svg image show up based on total number of members in the team. Following are some important points:

- Some members have scores and some don't
- Each person SVG image represent a member in the team
- The color for the SVG team should map to the score value
- The score value ranges from 1 - 5

I've created the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u6u6sn?ctl=1&devtoolsheight=33&embed=1) to show what I've done in Angular and d3 v5. For some reason, the images are not showing in StackBlitz but it works on my local machine.

**Ask**

The problem I'm facing is that the color on the Person images do not match with the color legend and value. I couldn't figure out why neither how to fix it.

The image currently looks like this:

[image]

**The data**

```
this.teamScores = [
                          {
                              "memberPersonID": "2892082",
                              "score": 3.8571
                          },
                          {
                              "memberPersonID": "2917522",
                              "score": 3
                          },
                          {
                              "memberPersonID": "2917524",
                              "score": 3.2857
                          },
                          {
                              "memberPersonID": "2917517",
                              "score": 3.2857
                          },
                          {
                              "memberPersonID": "2917520",
                              "score": 3.4286
                          },
                          {
                              "memberPersonID": "2917519",
                              "score": 3
                          },
                          {
                              "memberPersonID": "2917523",
                              "score": 3.1429
                          }
                      ]
```

Please note the score values and the legend. The colors currently do not seem like it's mapping to the actual score.

Comment: If we can't see the images, how can we help you? Try using dummy images otherwise, and show us an image of what it looks like on your machine.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot, the image is there. It's in the folder `assets/images`. For some reason, it's just not showing up in stackblitz. Must be something with the path selection?

Comment: Could be, but since that doesn't work, just use a dummy image instead. It shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @RubenHelsloot, sorry I misunderstood. Added the images in the question above. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Because of your image, I now see that it was a simple SVG path, and not something more complex. I was able to show the images using the following code instead of the xml image.

```javascript
defs.html(`<g>
  <circle cx="26.686" cy="4.507" r="4.507"/>
  <path d="..."/>
</g>`);
```

Comment: @RubenHelsloot, that's cool! Thanks for sharing. Now I know that's also a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your images weren't coloring was that your colorRange was empty. The reason for that was the following:

```js
var colorRange = d3.range(0, 1, 1.0 / grads.length - 1);
```

Here, the last argument is calculated as `(1.0 / grads.length) - 1 = 0.11111 - 1 = -0.8888`, which is a negative number. Therefore the range was empty, which made all persons black.

Changing this to `var colorRange = d3.range(0, 1, 1.0 / (grads.length - 1));` fixed it.

Comment: That still didn't show me proper coloring. The images do show different colors, but it doesn't match with the values in the legend. If you notice the `score` values in the data above and match it with colors, those don't match and is misleading to people who read the visualization. Even though one person has a value of 3.4, the color seems to be for ~ 1-2.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. In line number 126, I changed it from `minscore` and `maxscore` to `[1,5]` since that's the value that the legend was created using.

Comment: Good to hear, consider adding it as an answer so future people with the same question can find it more easily!